# Browser - Prevent autocompletion box from showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to prevent the autocompletion box from showing?

[image]

As you can see I am showing a datetime picker, but there is a autocompletion box in the way. Can I prevent it from showing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the autocomplete `attribute` on your calendar input which may appear something like this:

```
<input autocomplete="username">
```

Try switch to false?

```
<input autocomplete="false">
```

Comment: There is no autocomplete attribute on my input.

Comment: Eh.. Sorry I forgot to update my answer